# Having trouble displaying data from an API. ngFor only supports binding to iterables such as arrays

Tags: angular, api, ngfor

so I'm using RAWG API to return some data on the Sonic The Hedgehog video game series but running into [this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8jMG.png) in the console while trying to do

`<div>
    <li *ngFor="let games of gamesData">{{games.name}}</li>
</div>`

in the html

**This is what my service.ts looks like**

```
  export class RawgApiService {

  private _url = "https://api.rawg.io/api/games?search=sonic&developers=sega"

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {

  }

  public getGameData(): Observable<RAWGResponse> {
    return this.httpClient.get<RAWGResponse>(this._url)
    .pipe(
    tap(data => console.log('GameData/error' + JSON.stringify(data))
    ),
    catchError(this.handleError)
  );
  }

  private handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse) {
    console.log('IGDBApiService: ' + err.message);
    return Observable.throw(err.message);
  }
```

}

**And this is the component**

```
export class ListGamesComponent implements OnInit {

 gamesData:RAWGResponse;
 errorMessage:any;

constructor(private gameService: RawgApiService) {}

  ngOnInit(){
   this.getGameDetails();
}

getGameDetails() : boolean{
  this.gameService.getGameData().subscribe(
    gamesData => {
      this.gamesData = gamesData;
      console.log("data: " + JSON.stringify(this.gamesData))
    },
    error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
  );
  return false;
}
```

}

Any ideas would be appreciated and sorry if the question is poorly made any clarifications needed just ask, thanks in advance

Comment: What is the output of `console.log("data: " + JSON.stringify(this.gamesData))`?

Comment: @KariF. Yesterday I seem to remember it outputting something like data: unknown, but now it doesn't seem to be outputting anything in the console for some reason

Comment: @KariF. ok so I fiddled around with it a little and I've now got it in the console as `data: [object Object]`

Comment: And I can also get it to display `data: undefined` if I change some other things around

Comment: Sounds like `gamesData` is an object that wraps the real data. `ngFor` needs an array to iterate instead of an object. If that's the case you could extract the data from the object: `this.arrayData = this.gamesData.data;`. Check this demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vrerca